# Adding metadata to opus file from command line

Tags: audio, tagging

I have a collection of opus music files that needs tagging and a text file containing the appropriate tags. I'm trying to accomplish the tagging through a Python script but I need a way to edit the metadata of the opus files. So a CLI program that can tag opus files.

`opusenc`, which is part of `opus-tools` doesn't accept opus files as input. There are a lot of graphical programs that can edit the tags of opus files but that doesn't work in this case. I was thinking ffmpeg could do it but the [wiki page](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=FFmpeg_Metadata) doesn't mention opus (or ogg or flac which also uses a "Vorbis Comment" to store metadata as I understand it).

I assume my two suggestions would re-encode the files and I'm not sure if that will damage the sound quality. If so it would be preferable to use something that doesn't re-encode.

I'm running Manjaro Linux.

Comment: Care to share your script? I am about to do exactly the same thing.

Comment: What script are you referring to?

Comment: You wrote "I'm trying to accomplish the tagging through a Python script".

Comment: Ah, right. It grew into a fairly large program specifically for files downloaded with youtube-dl. Probably different from your usecase. What I recommend you do if you just want to move some data from text files into the tags of a music file is use the mutagen Python module: https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess I basically had the answer in my question. FFMpeg works just fine when I just decided to try it. It doesn't seem to re-encode because the process is instantaneous. I just did:

```
ffmpeg -i <input-file> -acodec copy -metadata title="<title>" -metadata artist=<artist> <output-file>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `opustags` at [fmang/opustags: Ogg Opus tags editor](https://github.com/fmang/opustags)

It can copy metadata from an input opus file and add the metadata you want.

There is a man page included for usage examples.